# how to make array groups using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the code to make arrays and access them.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(
            function() {
                var i;
                var mycars = new Array();
                mycars[0] = "Car1";
                mycars[1] = "Car2";
                mycars[2] = "Car3";
                mycars[3] = "Car4";
    var Car1 = {
   ownerName: "Owner1",
   phoneNumber: "phoneNumber1",
   address: "Address1"
}
var Car2 = {
   ownerName: "Owner2",
   phoneNumber: "phoneNumber2",
   address: "Address2"
}
var Car3 = {
   ownerName: "Owner3",
   phoneNumber: "phoneNumber3",
   address: "Address3"
}
                $("div#tabbable").tabs();

                // $("button#add-tab").click(function() {

                var num_tabs = $("div#tabbable ul li").length + 1;
                for (i = 0; i < mycars.length; i++) {

                    $("div#tabbable ul").append(
                            "<li><a href='#tab" + num_tabs + "'>" + mycars[i]
                                    + "</a></li>");

                     $("div#tabbable").append(
                     "<div id='tab" + num_tabs + "'>#" + mycars[i] + "</div>"
                     );                     $("div#tabbable").tabs("refresh");
                }

                //});                    
            });
</script>
    <body>

<!-- needed for tabbable population -->
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="span5 offset1">
                        <div id='tabbable'>
                            <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked">

                                <li> 
                                    <!-- <a href='#tab1'>#1</a> --></li>
                            </ul>
                            <!-- <div id='tab1'></div> -->
                        </div>
                        <!-- <button id='add-tab'>Add tab</button> -->

                    </div>

                </div>
<!-- end -->

</body>
```

What if I need the details of each car, like how do I make an array whicj is dependent on the mycars array.  when I am populating the car details using objects how do I get the details of car in this code?
How do I get these car details when clicked on the populated tabs???

Comment: Help me out..........when objects for car was created it fails to work!!!

Answer (score 0):

You should store [`Objects`](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp) instead of strings:

```
var Car1 = {
   ownerName: "Owner1",
   phoneNumber: "phoneNumber1",
   address: "Address1"
}
```

Accessing it by specifying field name:

```
alert(myCars[0].ownerName);
```

or

```
alert(myCars[0]["ownerName"]);
```

*Strongly recommend you to read about [OOP in JavaScript's world](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/oopjs.shtml)*

Comment: You are using wrong properties initialization for javascript objects. It's `:` instead of `=`.

Comment: @ArtyomNeustroev Thanks, updated) Just finished with writing come C# stuff and it's still in my mind.

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like:

```
var mycars = {};
mycars["car1"] = ["Owner1", "phone number1", "Address1"];
mycars["car2"] = ["Owner2", "phone number2", "Address2"];
mycars["car3"] = ["Owner3", "phone number3", "Address3"];
mycars["car4"] = ["Owner4", "phone number4", "Address4"];

for(var car in mycars) {
    // car = car1, car2, car 3, car4
    // mycars[car] = your array
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create an array of **Objects**, which would look like this:

```
function Car(settings) {
   this.Name = settings.Name;
   this.Owner = settings.Owner;
   this.Phone = settings.Phone;
   this.Address = settings.Address;
};
var mycars = [];
mycars.push(new Car({
   Name: "Car1",
   Owner: "Owner1",
   Phone: "Phone1",
   Address: "Address1"
}));
```

Then you can get an array item's properties like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < mycars.length; i++) {
   console.log(mycars[i].Name); 
   //or any other property, defined in Car constructor function
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use multidimentional array

```
 mycars = "{Car1:{ "Owner1", "phone number1", "Address1" }}";
```

i worked with this code for creating multidimentional array and get the information using car name like car1 , car2 etc